# How to call a function from another file

Tags: function, matlab

I have a livescript which is trying to call another function. This function is called "attempt1.m" and is located in the same location as the live script.

```
[f,A,b,staffNumberVector] = attempt1(staffTable,requirements);
```

However I generate the following error "undefined function or variable "attempt1""

Comment: are the file and the function inside the file the same name? never played with live scripts, but this shoudl work on a normal script. Have you tried it on a normal script?

Comment: Yes the function and file name are the same. I havent tried a normal script yet though

Comment: It works perfectly as a `.m` main script does. If that is not working using a live function `.mlx` will also work to save the function in a separate function from the function call.

Comment: It worked for a normal script so I have just changed the file format. It just didn't work for live script